# Getting 404 error with TOMCAT-Jersey Rest

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey

I am using JERSEY2.15:-

java class:-

```
package packages.newJersey;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/rest")
public class SimpleWebService {

    private static String versions = "4.1";

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String simpleMessage() {

        return "<p>This is a simple REST</p>";

    }

    @Path("/version")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String version() {

        return "<p>Version Number:</p> " + versions;

    }
}
```

web.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>LatestJersey</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.package</param-name>
            <param-value>packages.newJersey</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

even though i use display name as :- LatestJersey

by default tomcat is opening:-
http://localhost:8080/RESTFULServiceWithLatestJersey/

and when i hit:-
http://localhost:8080/RESTFULServiceWithLatestJersey/hello/rest

**I AM GETTING 404 ERROR**

Could someone please help me here?

Comment: What is the exact message returned with 404 error? Also please provide the path to the SimpleWebService.class from tomcat home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything looks good, except for this

```
jersey.config.server.provider.package
```

It should be

```
jersey.config.server.provider.packages
```

You're missing the `s`

Comment: Working,Thanks!!!, but could u please tell me what is this jersey.config.server.provider.packages and why i use it here

Comment: Its just one of many possible Jersey configurations you can set. This particular one lists the packages Jersey should scan for your resources and providers. Since you spelled it wrong, the actual property was never set, so the package is never scanned and the resource is never loaded. Hence the 404 Not Found